# CakePHP: $this->model->find('all') crash all pages. Any idea of what happened?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and this is only the second PHP framework I learn. (Codeigniter is the first)

I followed the CakePHP blog tutorial on cakephp official sites and everything works fine. I like the idea that CakePHP that it automatically generate find('all') method. So I decided to give it another try by making my own model and call it on another method of the same Posts controller. (the one created following the tutorial) but then it returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 152861 bytes) in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\cakephpTesting\lib\cake\Log\Engine\FileLog.php on line 134
```

Or sometimes when I reload the page again, it gives another message:

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to View::__construct() must be an instance of Controller, array given [CORE\cake\view\View.php, line 320]

Fatal Error
Error: Call to undefined method View::find()    
File: D:\XAMPP\htdocs\cakephpTesting\app\Controller\PostsController.php 
Line: 10
```

This is the code I added to the controller in PostsController.php:

```
public function listView() {
    $this->loadModel('View');
    $this->View->find('all');
}
```

This is the code in the new Model (/app/model/View.php

```
<?php
    class View extends AppModel {
    }
?>
```

And the new table is just a direct copy of the tutorial except that the table name is now called "views".

I have created another /app/view/Post/list_view.ctp and it is a blank file.

I am using Cakephp 2.4.5 as suggested by the official site.

Have I missed anything? And why it is creating different error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like a naming collision, you have defined a class named `View` which was already defined in `[CORE\cake\view\View.php]` and is required for CakePHP to operate.

Change your file name to `MyView.php` and your class name to `MyView` and see if that clears up your issue.

Answer (score 1):

It is so terrible idea use $this->View->find('all');
Because if db data big you just cant take that data. It's about php.ini configuration.
So I recommending you take that data with some limit:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
   'limit' => 10// or what you want
));
```

Or use some conditions for optimise your request:

```
$this->Model->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array(
      //some conditions here etc...
   ),
   'limit' => 10// all time you need know what you need take on db, not just all
));
```

Or just use paginator if you want use that data in view with all data.
"ALL TIME" try maximally optimising your code!

Comment: Although you are not answering the question, thanks for your great advice.

Comment: Rob M. have successfully answered. I just remind you about better things. You welcome